# How to remove a nested tag from XML doc using QDomDocument

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qtxml, qdomdocument

I need to remove a nested multilevel (unknown depth) tag from a XML file using QDomDocument. What is the proper way of doing this? 
Here is a sample of XML file

```html
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      .............................
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Comment: Submitted a `QDomDocument` solution, too. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 4):

I would not even use `QDomDocument`, aka. `QtXml` for this as the stream reader and writer classes are relatively simple to use in QtCore. Here goes my solution that could be further extended to support other things, too:

## QtCore

#### testin.xml

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      .............................
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

#### testout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
    <B/>
</A>
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>

int main()
{
    QFile inputFile("testin.xml");
    if (!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "File open error:" << inputFile.errorString();
        return 1;
    }
    QFile outputFile("testout.xml");
    if (!outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "File open error:" << outputFile.errorString();
        return 1;
    }
    QXmlStreamReader inputStream(&inputFile);
    QXmlStreamWriter outputStream(&outputFile);
    outputStream.setAutoFormatting(true);
    outputStream.writeStartDocument();
    bool ignore = false;
    static const QString searchString = "C";
    while (!inputStream.atEnd() && !inputStream.hasError())
    {
        inputStream.readNext();
        if (inputStream.isStartElement()) {
            QString name = inputStream.name().toString();
            if (name != searchString && !ignore)
                outputStream.writeStartElement(name);
            else
                ignore = true;
        } else if (inputStream.isEndElement()) {
            if (!ignore)
                outputStream.writeEndElement();
            if (inputStream.name().toString() == searchString)
                ignore = false;
        }
    }
    outputStream.writeEndDocument();
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

## QtXml

If you still insist on using `QtXml` for this simple task, you could do this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QDomNode>
#include <QDomElement>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QFile inputFile("testin.xml");
    if (!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "File open error:" << inputFile.errorString();
        return 1;
    }

    QDomDocument doc;
    doc.setContent(&inputFile);
    QDomNode searchNode = doc.elementsByTagName("C").item(0);
    QDomNode parentNode = searchNode.parentNode();
    parentNode.removeChild(searchNode);
    qDebug() << doc.toString();
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core xml
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"<A>
 <B/>
</A>
"
```

Comment: I think I should have included that i "MUST" do this in QDomDocument since this is only a part of another project which is already implemented using QDomDocument.

Comment: You could've given the answer in two lines, without yelling at me so much. "You have to remove the child using parent nodes removeChild() member function" I was trying to do it before using the root elements removeChild() function. Thank you for pointing me at the right direction. And you didn't have to give build commands. I said I already implemented some part of the project right?

Comment: @Madushan: It's not all about you. An answer is also for future readers of your question.